# Проблема с хостингом

Tags: хостинг

С всех с Наступающим. У моего заказчика два одинаковых сайта. Первый рабочий, а второй ждёт пока первый отключиться. Проблема в том, что первый сайт находится на хостинге одного разработчика (он не выходит на связь) Мне просто интересно можно ли как-то убрать сайт с онлайна, если да то как?

Comment: Дождаться, пока его не отключат за неуплату?

Comment: А так если бы можно было убрать любой сайт по одному лишь желанию, то интернет уже давно сдох бы

Comment: Так проблема в том, что хостинг его домашний

Comment: таки то да, но может по авторским правам?

Comment: Ну если всё принадлежит ему, тогда никак. Разве что подать в суд на незаконное использование интеллектуальной собственности, но это прокатит только если оно действительно незаконное

Comment: Просто в чём проблема, первый сайт он не доделал и бросил, и вызвали меня. Я сделал сайт (прям такой же, но рабочий), но сказал, что если его запустить в онлайн, то гугл и яндекс посчитают его за плагиат и замутят его в продвижение через seo. Вот как быть с этим? может знаете

Comment: Ну это уже очевидный косяк заказчика, что сайт оформлен не на него и доступы тоже не у него

Comment: Если узнаете где сервер - то можно физически повлиять но вандализм и хулиганство не лучший путь.

Comment: @V.March хех, Это кака- та забава ради, если честно))

Answer (score 2):

Сервера, на которые приходят запросы для какого-то определённого доменного имени, устанавливаются в DNS зоне этого домена.

К примеру, есть доменное имя `example.com`. В DNS зоне прописано, что `www.example.com` имеет адрес `A.A.A.A`.

Предположим, что вы хотите ввести в эксплуатацию новый сервер `B.B.B.B`. Для этого в доменной зоне нужно исправить запись для `www.example.com` так, чтобы она содержала адрес `B.B.B.B`.

Владелец доменного имени и другие люди с соответствующими полномочиями могут это сделать. Многое зависит от того, где и как именно организовано управление DNS зоной домена - это может быть и предоставленный регистратором сервис с Web интерфейсом, а может быть она содержится на самостоятельно обслуживаемом компьютере дома или где-нибудь ещё.

Comment: То есть, если создать другой на другом домене такой же сайт, это не будет считать плагиатом? (там просто текст одинаковый)

Comment: Я не знаком с алгоритмами работы поисковых систем, так что ответить на этот вопрос я не смогу.

Comment: @КириллМитин, ВЛ80 дал Вам действительно полный ответ. Что касается плагиата - это может быть только в случае отправки жалобы на фишинг или нечто подобное. А так не запрещено иметь сайты с одинаковым контентом )